# Angular ui router redirect does't work

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm using ui.router for routing in my Angular app. This is a very simple app which have only 3 views: Home , FAQ and Contact.
I have define 3 different states for each page and define their template url, but no navigation is working at all.
No view template is loaded into my index.html.
I am attaching the following code

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router'])


app.config(['$stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider',function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
 
 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
 $stateProvider.state('home',{
  url:'/home',
  templateUrl:'Home.html'
 }).state('contact',{
  url:'/contact',
  templateUrl:'Contact.html'
 }).state('faq',{
  url:'/faq',
  templateUrl:'FAQ.html'
 })
}]);
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.18/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header">
   <a class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="#">AngularUI Router </a>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   <li><a ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
   <li><a ui-sref="faq">FAQ</a></li>
   <li><a ui-sref="contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
 <div class="container">
  <div ui-view></div>
 </div>
```

and my views are very simple one, for example Home.html

```
<div>
    Home Page!
</div>
```

Comment: Check that the path for templateUrl is correct. If you have the templates inside a folder the templateUrl should be `templates/Home.html`

Comment: the path is correct, I even stop using templateUrl and use template instead so my code is something like this:
url:'/home',
template: '<div>Home Page!</div>'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to close your dependencies quotes:

Just change

```
app.config(['$stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider',
```

To

```
app.config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider',
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3J1qitPqHxAyWJ4PxTQS?p=preview)

Comment: @Brk When this solved your issue, please mark this answer as the right one. I think you now only upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

> Even I faced the same problem in the beginning. I solved it by running
>   the application on a local server.

You can use brackets editor which has an inbuilt server.